# Dspace and Bitstream

Tags: dspace, bitstream

I installed Dspace 5.2 on a Linux system (CenOS) for testing and implementation at our University.  Everything works fin expect when I try to view/open any file attached to any item.  The browser tries to connect and download the file but nothing happens for a long time.

Following is a sample item with a couple of files.

http://ds.bethlehem.edu:8080/xmlui/handle/123456789/30

Appreciate your help

Comment: The 123456789/30 item cannot be found, I guess it was removed. But the 123456789/32 item works fine here.

Comment: Thanks for checking the issue.  I was able to resolve the problem.  It was our firewall blocking connections to google servers.  Everytime an item is viewed,  despise server connects to google servers.  Not sure why this happens,  especially that I did not enable google analytics.  Thanks again.  Philip

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem.  It was our firewall blocking connections to google servers.  Everytime an item is viewed,  despise server connects to google servers.  Not sure why this happens,  especially that I did not enable google analytics.

Comment: sounds very much like this known issue: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2718

Comment: Yes it is.  I hope they will resolve this in the next update.  Thanks Bram.